# MongoDB Rails3.2 Database command 'create' failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, osx-elcapitan

I'm having trouble configuring a new MacBookPro to run a Rails 3.2 app.

- Rails 3.2.12
- MongoDB 2.6.9
- Ruby 1.9.3

**Though I know that the code works, because it works for my coworkers**

- Coworkers exported the collections using `mongoexport`
- I then loaded the collections with `mongorestore`

From the error, it appears that mongo is attempting to recreate the collections on every request... but I know that I have restored the exported collections. 
Here is the error:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'create' failed: (ok: '0.0'; errmsg: 'collection already exists'; code: '48').
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/db.rb:526:in `command'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.6.2/lib/mongo/db.rb:297:in `create_collection'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/collections/master.rb:41:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/collection.rb:127:in `new'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/collection.rb:127:in `master'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/collection.rb:42:in `find'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/contexts/mongo.rb:93:in `count'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:45:in `count'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.12/lib/mongoid/finders.rb:39:in `count'
from (irb):1
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

We have attempted to only restore a subset of the collections, and also tried running a newer version of MongoDB server.  No luck, yet.
We're stumped.  Any help or suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: _ Coworkers exported _ Does it happen only on your machine even with the same codebase?

Comment: Sounds like you may have enabled strict mode.  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/tree/1.6.2#strict-mode

Answer (score 1):

> Can't figure out why it's throwing this error

It says pretty clear `errmsg: 'collection already exists'` so, did you check the database if the collections already exist? Also, did you check if your code is trying to create collections every time the app starts?

You can connect to the database and execute

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

This will show you the collections that had at least one document inserted into them, even if they are currently empty.

If you want to delete them to run your app, you can do

```
db.myColl.drop()
```

Comment: Yes the collection does exist; it was restored from an export. It looks like it is trying to recreate the collections every time but, since it isn't doing this for my coworkers, i'm attempting to figure out what might be wrong with the configuration I have that would throw that error code.